# Вывод не в той кодировке

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

url = 'http://wordsteps.com/ajax/ajax_handler.php?JsHttpRequest=16071836327431-xml'

r = requests.get(url)
# r.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(r.text)
print(r.encoding)
```

Вот такой вывод получаю:

```
{"id":"16071836327431","js":{"error":"\u0418\u0437\u0432\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435, \u043d\u0430\u043c \u043d\u0435 \u0443\u0434\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432\u044b\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0438\u0435. \u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u043c, \u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438 \u044d\u0442\u0430 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f."},"text":""}
UTF-8
```

**r.encoding = 'utf-8'** тоже не работает (комментарий). Хотя он, вроде как, в этой ситуации и не нужен.
Как исправить?

Comment: `r.json()`.....

Comment: Благодарю! Это помогло.